# Tallying and sorting a Class object element in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'key1': [<__main__.OrderRecord object at 0x02C70C90>], 'key2': [<__main__.OrderRecord object at 0x02C709B0>, <__main__.OrderRecord object at 0x02BC9AB0>], 'key3': [<__main__.OrderRecord object at 0x02C2F2B0>]}
```

The Class objects contain the following elements:

```
class OrderRecord:
"""The OrderRecord class
Data attributes: date of type str
                 location of type str
                 name of type str
                 colour of type str
                 ordernum of type int
                 cost of type int
"""

def __init__(self, file_line):
    """Takes a given file line and initialises an OrderRecord instance"""

    split_file = file_line.split(",")
    self.date = split_file[0]
    self.location = split_file[1]
    self.name = split_file[2]
    self.colour = split_file[3]
    self.ordernum = split_file[4]
    self.costs = self.cost_of_order()
```

What I need to do is to get is all the different colours in the Class objects (there is only 1 colour per object, but they could be the same as in other objects), and then a tally of the number of objects containing that colour.

The output would be something like this:

```
Colour variables:       No. of objects:    
Colour1                 2
Colour2                 1
Colour3                 1
...                    ...
```

Etc etc

I think I can obtain the information by taking it from the raw file data and just indexing into it with a for loop or something, but I just thought it would be easier to read the Class objects directly, if that is possible at all? Note that some keys can have a single list of multiple Class objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to use [`collections.counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

object_dict = {'key1': [<__main__.OrderRecord object at 0x02C70C90>]}
cnt = Counter()
for item_group in object_dict.values():
    for item in item_group:
        cnt[item.color] += 1
```

Then you can access the various information about the counts from the `cnt` Counter object, there's various methods such as [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) that you might find helpful.